# Cast IEnumerable interface to concrete type

Tags: c#

I have something like:

```
    public interface IThing
    {
        string Id { get; }
    }
    public class Ball : IThing
    {
        public string Id { get; }
    }

    public class Car : IThing
    {
        public string Id { get; }
    }
```

For my 3-4 functions I want to treat `Ball` and `Car` the same. I use the interface so I dont have to make overload methods (one for car, one for ball).

Finally, there is on function where I have different logic if its a `Ball` or a `Car`. I get a `IEnumerable<IThings>` and I want to cast it to either `IEnumerable<Car>` or `IEnumerable<Ball>` depending what it consists of. If it consists of a mix, I want it to fail. It has to be all cars or all balls.

I tried something like:

```
        var things = (inputs is IEnumerable<Ball>) ? input.Locations.Cast<Ball>() : input.Locations.Cast<Car>()
```

But it doesn't like that. What is the recommended approach where I can have 1 variable?

Edit:

The reason why I wanted to get it into one variable is because I am sending it to an overloaded method. So I want to do this:

```
        var things = (inputs is IEnumerable<Ball>) ? input.Locations.Cast<Ball>() : input.Locations.Cast<Car>()

        for (var i = 0; i < numRequests; i++)
        {
            var thingsSet = things.Skip(i * 1000).Take(1000);
            var results = callOverLoadedFunction(thingsSet);
        }
```

Rather than this:

```
        if (inputs is IEnumerable<Ball>)
        {
            var things = input.Locations.Cast<Ball>();
            for (var i = 0; i < numRequests; i++)
            {
                var thingsSet = things.Skip(i * 1000).Take(1000);
                var results = callOverLoadedFunction(thingsSet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var things = input.Locations.Cast<Car>();
            for (var i = 0; i < numRequests; i++)
            {
                var thingsSet = things.Skip(i * 1000).Take(1000);
                var results = callOverLoadedFunction(thingsSet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You use TWO variables :-) You already have TWO piece of code that do TWO different things... What is the problem in having TWO variables?

Comment: check for the very first element instead of casting to `IEnumerable<Ball>`: `var things = (inputs.First() is Ball) ? input.Locations.Cast<Ball>() : input.Locations.Cast<Car>()`

Comment: @HimBromBeere The only problem here is that you are enumerating twice the `IEnumerable<>`, normally not a good idea.

Comment: And you haven't specified if in the case of mixed `IEnumerable<>` it should fail at the start of enumeratio or after the different element is discovered... `new[] { Ball, Ball, Car }`... When should it fail? Immediately or when it should return `Car`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You're breaking the Substitution Principle here,  which is a major sign that your are doing something wrong.  If you have an IEnumerable of IThings you should only be acting upon them as IThings

Comment: The thing is, how do you imagine your code, when you have only ONE variable, but want to do TWO different things based on the type in the collection and you do NOT want to check via ``input is TYPE`` ?

You HAVE to do the ``if`` at some point. I still can not imagine, where you want to go...

Comment: What type is `inputs`? If it is `IEnumerable<IThing>` then that's the type and the `is` keyword will always yield false for a check versus `IEnumerable<Ball>`.

Comment: @Adwaenyth Is that so? What returns `myType m = new myType(); object o = m; return o is myType;`?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider it returns true because that is indeed the same type (it's even the same reference for that matter). An `IEnumerable<X>` is however a different type than `IEnumerable<Y>` even if `Y` inherits from `X`. Just look at xanatos' array a few comments up and you can see the problem.

Comment: @Adwaenyth I wonted to point out that the compile-time *declared* type and the run-time object type can differ. That is also true for Enumerations. Your statement "If it is IEnumerable<IThing> then that's the type and the is keyword will always yield false for a check versus IEnumerable<Ball>" is wrong if the `IEnumerable<IThing>` points to an object of type `IEnumerable<Ball>`. Cf. my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your attempt it this:

```
inputs is IEnumerable<Ball>
```

Because an `IEnumerable<IThing>` that only contains elements of type `Ball` is *not* the same type as `IEnumerable<Ball>`. You really have no choice but to enumerate through your collection to determine if every item matches the type you require. You could use `.Cast<...>()` and handle the `InvalidCastException`, but that's a little bit hacky. Another way would be to use `OfType<...>`:

```
var cars = inputs.OfType<Car>();
var balls = inputs.OfType<Ball>();
```

And now you can deal with them as you wish, for example:

```
if(balls.Any() && cars.Any())
{
    //You're not allowed to have balls and cars together
    throw new Exception(...);
}
```

However, you are really breaking the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) of SOLID here, it seems like you should consider at a higher level what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a convert method, but that would still break some principles, as you still have to place an `if` statement.
I am not sure, you are using interfaces the right way with what you want to achieve.

If you want a `car` to behave different from a `ball` in a specific situation, then the implementation in the car shall **do** something different than the implementation in the ball.

Do not try to tweak an interface from outside. The implementations have to do this.

Why not create a method `DoMySpecialStuff` in `IThing` and you just iterate over your enumerable in this one special method that just calls `DoMySpecialStuff` on all the elements?
That's the way you can avoid your if-statement.

I just saw your edit with your `overloadedMethod`

So it could work like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numRequests; i++)
    {
        var thingsSet = things.Skip(i * 1000).Take(1000);
        var results = callOverLoadedFunction(thingsSet);
    }

void OverLoadedFunction(IThing thing)
{
    thing.DoSpecialStuff(); // This does different things in car/ball
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate balls and cars from each other using LINQ

```
IEnumerable<Ball> balls = things.OfType<Ball>();
IEnumerable<Car> cars = things.OfType<Car>();
```

If you want it to fail and like one line solutions try something like this

```
IEnumerable<Ball> balls = things.OfType<Ball>().Count() == things.Count() ? things.OfType<Ball>() : null; //or whatever you want
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to redo something I did some time ago: the retransformation of partially a enumerated `IEnumerator<>` to full `IEnumerable<>`. This solves a problem that I feel is important: you shouldn't enumerate twice "unknown" `IEnumerable<>` (for "unknown" I mean `IEnumerable<>` that you haven't built by hand in the same method but that are of unknown origin), because there is no guarantee that it can be done, and even if it can be done, you could cause the big work needed to generate the `IEnumerable<>` to be done twice.

```
public class RemainingIEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Enumerable { get; set; }

    public int Nulls { get; set; }
    public T First { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<T> Enumerator { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var enumerator = Enumerator;

        if (enumerator == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        return GetEnumerableRemaining().GetEnumerator();
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerableRemaining()
    {
        var enumerator = Enumerator;
        Enumerator = null;

        int nulls = Nulls;
        Nulls = 0;

        T first = First;
        First = default(T);

        for (int i = 0; i < nulls; i++)
        {
            yield return default(T);
        }

        yield return first;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public static bool Is<T>(IEnumerable<T> enu, Type type, out IEnumerable<T> enu2)
{
    IEnumerator<T> enumerator = null;

    int nulls = 0;

    try
    {
        enumerator = enu.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = enumerator.Current;

            if (current == null)
            {
                nulls++;
                continue;
            }

            enu2 = new RemainingIEnumerator<T>
            {
                Enumerable = enu,
                Nulls = nulls,
                First = current,
                Enumerator = enumerator,
            };

            enumerator = null;
            return current.GetType() == type;
        }

        // Only nulls case
        enu2 = new T[nulls];
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (enumerator != null)
        {
            enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Is<T>()` function returns true if the first non-`null` element is of the type `type`. It returns a new `IEnumerable<>` that can be used and that, through "magic", reuses the `IEnumerable<>` that was passed to `Is<>` (in some way it restitches the optional initial `null`s, the first found element and the unused remaining `IEnumerator<>`).

Example of use:

```
var enu1 = new object[] { null, new Dog(), new Cat(), new Dog() };

IEnumerable<object> enu2;

// From this line onward, you should use at least one enu2!
// It is the partially unwinded enu1 that has been rewinded through
// some magic :-)
bool isDog = Is(enu1, typeof(Dog), out enu2);

if (isDog)
{
    // Note the use of enu2!
    foreach (Dog dog in enu2.Cast<Dog>())
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<IThing> testCollection = new List<IThing>();
        testCollection.Add(new Ball());
        testCollection.Add(new Car());
        try
        {
        if (testCollection[0] is Ball)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testCollection.Cast<Ball>().Count().ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testCollection.Cast<Car>().Count().ToString());
        }
        }
        catch(InvalidCastException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mix isn't allowed!");
        }
    }
}

 public interface IThing
    {
        string Id { get; set;}
    }
    public class Ball : IThing
    {
        public string Id { get;set; }
    }

    public class Car : IThing
    {
        public string Id { get;set; }
    }
```

This code will throw an InvalidCastException at the call to `Cast<Ball>` as the `Car` object can't be cast to `Ball`. This should do what you wanted, if I'm not mistaken.

The code will only check the type of the first element, as the `List` shouldn't be mixed, it can be assumed that all the other objects in that `List` should have the same type, if not that's, in my opinion and from how the question was written, appropiate cause to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `IEnumerable<>` is covariant, that is, you can substitute `IEnumerable<Derived>` whenever an `IEnumerable<Base>` is needed.

If you have only pure containers of things, that is only things of the same kind are in a given container, then you should make that container (which will be passed as an IEnumerable at some point) of that specific type. For example a factory could produce a true list of cars, a `List<car>`, in code like `IEnumerable<Thing> things = factory.produceList(ThingTypes.Car);`. Like all types, `IEnumerable<>` objects retain their actual type information even when they get assigned to references of a more basic type. This type can be used to distinguish the actual type of the `IEnumerable<>` at run-time.

Perhaps some code is easier to understand. I create two `IEnumerable<I>`s with elements of two distinct types which both implement the same interface `I`. As I said, I can assign an `IEnumerable<T>` to an `IEnumerable<I>` as long as `T` implements `I`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    interface I { };
    class T1 : I { }
    class T2 : I { }

    class Program
    {
        // strongly typed arrays get assigned to base type IEnumerables.
        static IEnumerable<I> i1 = new T1[] { new T1(), new T1() };
        static IEnumerable<I> i2 = new T2[] { new T2(), new T2() };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Note: compile-time type of array elements is IEnumerable<I>!
            IEnumerable<I>[] iEnumArr = new IEnumerable<I>[] { i1, i2 };

            foreach (IEnumerable<I> ie in iEnumArr)
            {
                // ... but the run-time types of the IEnumerable objects 
                // are actually different.
                Console.WriteLine("ienumerable is of T1: " + (ie is IEnumerable<T1>));
                Console.WriteLine("ienumerable is of T2: " + (ie is IEnumerable<T2>));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
ienumerable is of T1: True
ienumerable is of T2: False
ienumerable is of T1: False
ienumerable is of T2: True
```

Edit of the edit: I see that you are working with `thingsSet` which is a true `IEnumerable<Thing>`. True, then the type tests don't work any longer.

<strike>Edit: Your edit is a bit unclear to me, but I assume that your overloaded method has two (or n) versions, one for an `IEnumerable<car>` and one for an `IEnumerable<ball>`. In that case I would do everything which is independent on the concrete type of the `Thing` first, and then distinguish only for the part where it matters. For example:</strike>

```
    for (var i = 0; i < numRequests; i++)
    {
        var thingsSet = things.Skip(i * 1000).Take(1000);

        // I may see your problem: Now with thingsSet we have true 
        // Enumerables of Thing, and the tests below are always false.
        // Hm.
        var carSet = thingsSet as IEnumerable<car>;
        var ballSet = thingsSet as IEnumerable<ball>;
        bool results;
        if(carSet != null ) { results = callOverLoadedFunction(carSet); }
        else if(ballSet != null) { results = callOverLoadedFunction(ballSet); }
        else { throw /*...*/}
    }
```

This solution has a bit of a code smell; ideally the calling code whouldn't be concerned with the concrete type of things. One possibility is to leave the "branching" for the distinct types to the `Thing`s. Or if that isn't possible, provide a single `callNonOverLoadedFunction(IEnumerable<Thing>)` with then branches internally, invisible to the caller. These functions are probably closer to the `Things` implementation and "know" which different types of `Things` exist; your calling code does not, and does not want to know, from a maintenance perspective.